# How to send httponly cookie with axios?

Tags: django, cookies, axios, create-react-app, httponly

I'm using a django backend, and a CRAO frontend. I saved the jwt refresh token as a httponly cookie:

```
document.cookie = `refresh=${refresh_token}; SameSite=Strict; Path=/api/token/refresh; HttpOnly`;
```

Then to refresh the access token, I'm sending an axios request:

```
const response = await axios.post('/api/token/refresh/', { withCredentials: true });
```

But, in this case, the originally saved cookies don't get sent by axios. However, on removing the httponly attribute, the cookies do get sent, and everything works fine.

Comment: the point of `httponly` cookies is that they cant be touched in any way by the clientside (ie. javascript).

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I see. Thanks for clarifying that. I was aware of it, but hadn't realized that they won't be sent automatically over a request either. Do you have any other recommendations to achieve this?

Comment: achieve _what_?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the cookie well in your django app. follow up this way to save it as httponly cookie:

```
response.set_cookie(
        key=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH"],
        value=token["refresh"],
        expires=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME"],
        secure=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE"],
        httponly=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY"],
        samesite=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE"],
    )
```

Comment: after cookies is been set as httponly how i can send it with axios request while i can't read it with js